# Jenkins: How to merge some common files from one repo to another

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

2 repos, repo1 and repo2, having different folder structure. There are some common source files exist in both repos. After successful build, need to merge changed files from the common files from repo1 to repo2.

Here's what I've so far and it's not complete and I'm stuck on how to move further; is there a better way to achieve this?

```
def filesNames      = ""
def filesNamesList  = ""
def files2push      = []
def branch          = env.GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION     
//files that need to be pushed from repo1 to repo2 once build is successful
def getFileMap(file){
    def repo1Repo2FileMap = [:]
    def repo1Repo2FileMap = ["dir1/dir2/file1.h" : "dir1/file1.h",
                            "fldr1/fldr2/file2.h" : "fldr2/file2.h"
                            ]
    return  repo1Repo2FileMap."$file"
}
//get changed files list
def getChanged(branch){
    def headRevision = sh (script: "git ls-remote | grep refs/heads/${branch} | head -n 1 | awk \'{print \$1}\'",
                            returnStdout: true)

    headRevision = headRevision.replaceAll("[\n\r]","")
    def getChangedList = sh (
        returnStdout: true,
        script: "git diff --name-only  $headRevision"
    ).trim().readLines().collect()
    if(getChangedList !=""){
        files = readFile(file: getChangedList)
        fileName = files.readLines()
        fileNameList = fileName.join(" ")
    }
    return changedFileNameList
}
stage("Push files to repo2"){
    
    getChanged(branch).each{
        if(getFileMap(it)){
            //eg: cp dir1/dir2/file1.h dir1/file1.h
            cp $file $it
            files2push.add(it)
        }
    }
}
stage("Merge Changed files to repo2"){
    dir("repo2"){
        bat """
            git add $files2push
            git commit -m "commit msg"
            git push
        """
    }
}
```

How to handle merge conflict case, common files in repo2 could be edited by someone else when jenkins tries to merge. What I'm thinking is to log the merge conflict and let the user handle it by fixing the merge conflict and retriggering the jenkins job.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a better way to achieve this?

Yes. Git subtree

- Move **all** shared files into **new** location
- Change and verify all references on moved sources
- Create *3-rd* repo from shared resources-folder
- Delete shared resources-folder from both repos
- Add resources-repo with git subtree to the former location of resources-folder into both repos
- Check all
- Have fun

Comment: I'm not familiar with subtree, having said that in order to move all shared files first I need to identify those files for that I still need the repo file map and traverse though them. Also, common files are spread out in multiple folders so how can I delete shared resouces-folder from the repos.